# facebook phonegap plugin does not show up in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, cordova

want to do the first time something with xcode and phonegap. Because I am doing a lot of facebook apps, I want to build a native iOS app with Facebook Login.

Followed the Steps here: https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect

Got the problem, that the plugin doesnt show up.

I copied it like this in the Plugin Folder of my project:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueYk0.png

But it is now displayed in Xcode as yellow folder or files in the project structure.

Think that it is logical, that I got the following error:

```
["org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect2","org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect","init",["471175846247043"]]
2012-10-04 21:10:19.015 HelloWorld[5476:c07] CDVPlugin class FacebookConnectPlugin (pluginName: org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect) does not exist.
2012-10-04 21:10:19.017 HelloWorld[5476:c07] ERROR: Plugin 'org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in Cordova.plist.
2012-10-04 21:10:19.018 HelloWorld[5476:c07] FAILED pluginJSON = ["org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect3","org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect","getLoginStatus",[]]
2012-10-04 21:10:23.571 HelloWorld[5476:c07] CDVPlugin class FacebookConnectPlugin (pluginName: org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect) does not exist.
2012-10-04 21:10:23.573 HelloWorld[5476:c07] ERROR: Plugin 'org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in Cordova.plist.
2012-10-04 21:10:23.575 HelloWorld[5476:c07] FAILED pluginJSON = ["org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect4","org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect","login",["email"]]
```

Comment: have you declared permission to use the plugin? or isn't that necesary for iOS?

Answer (score 1):

You are just missing a property list configuration. Do the following, per README instructions:

Find the Cordova.plist file in the project navigator, expand the "Plugins" sub-tree, and add a new entry. For the key, add org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect, and its value will be FacebookConnectPlugin

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add an entry to Cordova.plist. "org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect," for the key and FacebookConnectPlugin for the value.

Then, make sure you already have create a Facebook app and put your bundle ID in the Native IOS app section. Don't forget to enable login too.

Answer (score 0):

I had to revert back to this for it to work:

```
<plugin name="org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect" value="FacebookConnectPlugin" />
```

I wanted to use this, but I got the error message you referred to:

```
<feature name="org.apache.cordova.facebook.Connect">
    <param name="ios-package" value="FacebookConnectPlugin" />
</feature>
```